# Adapting Store decoding for streaming library

Tags: haskell, haskell-streaming

I am trying to adapt [`Store`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.9/store-0.4.3.2/Data-Store-Streaming.html) encoding and decoding for [`Streaming`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.7/streaming-0.2.0.0/Streaming.html). `Store` already implements a  streaming [`decode`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.9/store-0.4.3.2/src/Data.Store.Streaming.html#conduitDecode) with a function called `decodeMessageBS`.

I tried to do a basic implementation of `store` deserialization for `Streaming` as below (without `bracket` for now to keep it simple). However, there seems to be something wrong with the logic for `popper` because `decodeMessageBS` keeps throwing `PeekException`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE  RankNTypes #-}
import Streaming.Prelude as S hiding (print,show)
import Data.IORef
import Streaming as S
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS (ByteString,empty,length)
import System.IO.ByteBuffer
import Data.Store
import Data.Store.Streaming

streamDecode :: forall a. (Store a) => ByteBuffer -> Stream (Of BS.ByteString) IO () -> Stream (Of a) IO ()
streamDecode bb inp = do
    ref <- lift $ newIORef inp 
    let popper = do
        r <- S.uncons =<< readIORef ref
        case r of
          Nothing -> return Nothing 
          Just (a,rest) -> writeIORef ref rest >> return (Just a)
    let go = do
          r <- lift $ decodeMessageBS bb $ popper
          lift $ print "Decoding"
          case r of 
            Nothing -> return ()
            Just msg -> (lift $ print "Message found") >> (S.yield . fromMessage $ msg) >> go
    go
```

I can decode my test file fine with `decodeIOPortionWith` - so, the problem seems to be in the logic needed to feed `decodeMessageBS`. Will appreciate pointers on what is wrong with the logic of `popper` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PeekException` happens because `Store` uses a different format when saving messages in streaming mode, unlike `Binary`. It expects a wrapper of type `Message` around `Store` data when using `decodeMessageBS` function. `decodeIOPortionWith` doesn't expect `Message` wrapper  and so, works fine with saved down `Store` data. After I fixed the serialization to save down the data as `Message` encoding, `decodeMessageBS` worked fine on that data.